# How to detect the version of the compiler that is compiling my java source file

Tags: java

Hi I am writing a Java class that enables some of its functionalities when it is compiled with java7 upwards.
I know how to find the major/minor magic number from a **compiled** class file. But I need to find a way to detect that when the compiler is compiling my source code.
A simple snippet for this:
```

```
public class Hey
{
    public static final boolean JAVA_VER = ???; // how to do this??
    public static foo() {
        if (JAVA_VER >= JAVA7) {
            // use the fancy way introduced in java7
        } else {
            // go with the slow way of java6
        }
    }
}
```

```

Comment: This feels like an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is not executed during compilation. During compilation it is checked for syntactical errors and converted to byte code inside a .class file. Code lines can be executed when it is run and hence the only thing you can find out in your code is java runtime version. Java runtime can be found using java.version system property. Here is the code for that:

```
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

If you want to check the java compiler version, perhaps then you use a script to compile your code. Maybe you can have two different versions of your file, each one apt for one particular java version. In your script check the available java version and compile the desired version of file. You may want to use single output common output directory.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* be impossible. The compiler requires that the JVM running the code have the same version as the code being run - in essence, you cannot compile that for a lower version because the higher version code needs a higher version compiler.

In the case you were able to get around this, I would probably pack a script as mentioned before, or programmatically do so in a bootstrap by executing a byte code dump (which specified the major/minor version) either with Process or source decoding from the File bytes.